# Espresso: How fast show new activity?

Tags: android-espresso

I test my app by Android Espresso.

I have 2 activites. When click on some button in first activity then open second activity.

The question is: How fast show second activity? When activity show slower then 1 second ---> then need to fail test.

Is it possible to test this on Espresso?